# An infinite dimensional Banach spaces and hyperplan

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional banach space .And let $H$ be an hyperplan .I want an example of infinite-dimensional banach space $X$ which isn't isomorphic to hyperplan $H$ .

Comment: [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960)

Comment: For closed hyperplanes, this is non-trivial. See [this](https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/26/6/523/400892?redirectedFrom=fulltext). For an example with $H$ non-closed, I think you can take $H$ to be the kernel of a discontinuous linear functional on $X$.